# status check for sleep command

Tags: shell, shell-script, find, tcsh, sleep

I have run `sleep` command in **background** as follow , How can I know the status of execution ..?

### Command

```
sleep 2d ; find /home/disk1/ -exec touch {} \; &
```

How can I know that its executed for 1 day of `sleep` or is executing `find`command right now.

Comment: No, you've run `sleep` in the foreground. And when it completes `find` will run in the background.

Comment: if I run `sleep` in background would I have access to terminal? Cause I am able to access terminal right after executing the above command, and `jobs` state that its been executed.

Comment: With the above command you have type-ahead access to the terminal but anything you type won't get executed until the `sleep` is finished and the `find` starts running in the background. If you run `sleep` in the background you would have (almost) immediate access to the terminal. To run a set of commands in the background you can enclose the command in `{` and `}` with an `&` at the end of the line, as illustrated in Costa's answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can enclose the commands in `(` and `)` instead of `{` and `}` (still with `&` at the end of the line), which runs the commands in a subshell. See Compound Commands in the bash man page for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ touch /tmp/sleep.flag; sleep 2d ; rm /tmp/sleep.flag; find /home/disk1/ -exec touch {} \; ; } &
```

Everything what you need just check `/tmp/sleep.flag` file existance

```
[ -f /tmp/sleep.flag ] && echo "Running sleep..."
```

Comment: you mean that after execution of `sleep` after 2days the file will be deleted. right!

Comment: @JigarGandhi: Yes. At the end of two days the temporary file `/tmp/sleep.flag` will be deleted and the `find` command will start running. The whole group of commands (everything enclosed by `{` and `}`) is run in the background so you get access to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ps` to look for the sleep command:

```
{ sleep 20; find ...; } &
parent=$!
if ps --ppid $parent | grep sleep
then
    echo Sleep is running
fi
```